# doAnswer() equivalent in Spock

Tags: junit, spock, vert.x

I am new to Spock and trying to achieve below scenario:

```
@Test
public void asynchronousMethodTest() {
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.put("name", "Lilly").put("city", "Glendale");
    AsyncResult<JsonObject> asyncResult = Mockito.mock(AsyncResult.class);
    when(asyncResult.succeeded()).thenReturn(true);
    when(asyncResult.result()).thenReturn(jsonObject);
    doAnswer(new Answer<AsyncResult<JsonObject>>() {
        @Override
        public AsyncResult<JsonObject> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            ((Handler<AsyncResult<JsonObject>>) invocation.getArguments()[1]).handle(asyncResult);
            return null;
        }
    }).when(someService).callSomeService(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
    childVerticle.asynchronousMethod();

    //verify(someService, times(1)).callSomeService(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
}
```

What is spock equivalent to the above code?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible, please have a look at [this](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/interaction_based_testing.html#_computing_return_values) part of the documentation. Here's the relevant part:

```
subscriber.receive(_) >> { args -> args[0].size() > 3 ? "ok" : "fail" }
```

where `subscriber` is defined a a `Mock`.